# social-auth-app-django 'social' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

Python(3.6.7) and Django(2.1), trying to integrate *social-auth-app-django*.

Unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208212/python-social-auth-app-django-social-is-not-a-registered-namespace), I've declared `SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE` but it doesn't work.

Configuration :

### settings.py :

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "Microlly",
    "social_django",
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware"
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "microblogging.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
{
    "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
    "DIRS": [],
    "APP_DIRS": True,
    "OPTIONS": {
        "context_processors": [
            "django.template.context_processors.debug",
            "django.template.context_processors.request",
            "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
            "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            "social_django.context_processors.backends",
            "social_django.context_processors.login_redirect",
        ]
    },
}
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "microblogging.wsgi.application"

SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY="SECRET"
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET="SECRET"

SOCIAL_AUTH__KEY="ID"
SOCIAL_AUTH__SECRET="SECRET"

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"
},
{"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator"},
{"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator"},
{"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator"},
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/accounts/"

EMAIL_BACKEND = (
"django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
)  # During development only
```

### urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import include, path, reverse_lazy

from Microlly import views

app_name = "Microlly"


urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
url('^api/v1/', include("social_django.urls", namespace='social'))
]
```

### login.html

```
<a href="{% url "social:begin" "google-oauth2" %}">Google+</a>
```

And the returned error is :

> NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
>   'social' is not a registered namespace

So, **how can I register this namespace**, or is the issue anywhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

contrary to what you might think the **order** in which you **import** your django apps **matters a lot** in django, it might be a problem in which your app is using the contrib.auth yet it is calling some parts of it before it is instantiated.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
"Microlly",   <-------------move down
"social_django",   <--------------move down
"django.contrib.admin",
"django.contrib.auth",
"django.contrib.contenttypes",
"django.contrib.sessions",
"django.contrib.messages",
"django.contrib.staticfiles",
]
```

try putthing those custom ones on the bottom and tell me if it persists.

as you can see, on the link you posted the custom apps are called the last ones so they can use auth and admin

Comment: did you change the installe apps? can you copy ur code?